# What is the best way to adjust pocket doors stuck on carpet?

Tags: pocket-door

We had new carpet installed with a thicker pad.  Now the pocket doors stick on the carpet.  What is the best way to get at them to adjust them?  The best options I have come up with is to remove the trim (which I do not want to do) or cut a hole in the drywall and repair it (which I may do).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pocket doors can usually be adjusted by turning/twisting an adjustment screw at the top (sometimes a wheel at the bottom depending on the door). The door should allow for this adjustment somewhere without removing anything.

Comment: It does have adjustment screws, but I can't get at them with the trim on the door.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say without seeing them in person, but a lot of times there is some way to detach them from the track they are on. I would look carefully at the track to see if there is a removable section.